# Is there is a way to check the status of multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I used a deamon multiprocessing from python, to run a task in a file called `get.py`. After the multiprocessing-task is completed, it will automatically terminated. The main program is a loop, inside the loop, I used multiprocessing to do other task.

```
def new_process():
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=(self, queue_from_cam))
    process.daemon = True
    process.start()
    process.join(timeout_limit)
    if process.is_alive():
        process.terminate()

while True:
    new_process()
    #do rest of the calculations
```

After some time, the main process continues the execution but the deamon multiprocess is stopped without any exception, the process hanged there.

Then, main function continues execution without running the `new_process()` and it runs only the "do rest of the calculations" part.

The `fun` in Process statement, is for doing I/O operation from `txt` files, there I did not get any errors - I need to know what happens really

Is there any way to check in the ubuntu terminal about the status of deamon multiprocess created in a python script?

How to get to know why the process stopped?, Is there any logs are saved in python side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_alive() method -

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(value,))
p.start()

while p.is_alive():
    print("still running...")
    print(f"process Value: {value.value}")
    multiprocessing.active_children()
```

Then you can use `ps aux | grep python_file.py`, too see the process status

Comment: thanks for writing, I am searching for checking the status of the python process outside of the running script

Comment: Then you can try using below command -

`ps aux | grep python`